# Search & replace in bash output during execution

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Maybe with sed or awk or eval?

---

For example if I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo a
sleep 2
echo b
sleep 2
echo c
```

I'm wanting to run something like:

```
sed 's/a/x/' < `exampleScript.sh`
```

and after one second see the output:

```
x
```

and after three seconds see the output:

```
x
b
```

and after it finishes see the output:

```
x
b
c
```

(My actual use-case is some unicode characters that aren't displaying correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write the commands as a pipeline:

```
./exampleScript.sh | sed 's/a/x/'
```

If your shell is bash, you can include the sed inside the script itself by changing the first line to use bash specifically, and adding an `exec` with [bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) of stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >( sed 's/a/x/' )

echo a
sleep 2
echo b
sleep 2
echo c
```

Note that the space in `> >(` is required to avoid ambiguity.

---

Your desired timing doesn't seem to match your sample script.

If you really want an extra second delay, you can add it:

```
./exampleScript.sh | ( sleep 1; sed 's/a/x/' )
```

or use `exec` of:

```
exec > >(sleep 1; sed 's/a/x/')
```